# Getting JWT from Response Headers in Angular

Tags: angular

I have a Spring backend and a Angular frontend. I am trying to finish up creating the login in Angular. With postman I can get the jwt and the login and all of the routes work. In angular, when I sign-in, I can see in the Response Headers the JWt. My question is how can I get it and store it localStorage or anything? My response headers look like this: https://ibb.co/RgrGznR

My code is kind of a mess at this moment after trying so many different things. I was probably close at some point and in my frustration I have just went back to something very basic that just at least give me the Status 200 and the jwt in the response headers..

Here is my service class:

```
    export class DataService {
    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
      };

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

   }

  public login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/login', {username, 
password});
  }
```

and the login component:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

loginForm: FormGroup;
invalidLogin = false;

constructor(private router: Router, private service: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.loginForm = new FormGroup({
  username: new FormControl(''),
  password: new FormControl('')
 });
}

doLogin() {
 const username = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
 const password = this.loginForm.get('password').value;

 this.service.login(username, password).subscribe(
  data => {

  }

 );
}
}
```

I'm sorry, I have probably read over what I needed to do and just did not implement it correctly on my end.. I'm pretty decent with Java with the back end.. but I have not really messed with Angular too much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read the documentation, which should help you: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: Thank you! I will read over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DataService get the full response to access the headers:

```
  public login(username: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/login', {username, 
password}, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(res => {
      this.authToken = res.headers.get('Authorization');
      return res.body;
});
```

Here you can save the token and add it to your headers on subsequent requests.